# populate a list with a portion of the string in another list until i reach a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = ["Its_My_Life_3:44","Say_It_Isn't_So_3:33","Thank_You_for_Loving_Me_5:09"]
b = []
```

I want `b` to look like this

```
b = ["Its My Life","Say It Isn't So","Thank You for Loving Me"]
```

This is the code I'm struggling with, I'm struggling to find a condition that will only append the song name, replace `_` with `" "` and not include the number. I know I can do something with format and replace but I cant figure it out.

```
for song in a:
    b.append(song[0:8)]) #
    print(b)
```

Comment: Would you have something like `"99_Luftballons_3:53"` (numbers in name) or `"Amarok_60:02"` (10 or more minutes in length)?

Comment: That's exactly my issue! not all tracks have numbers at the end. That's why i was looking for a more generic statement "if possible" to drop all the numbers and take the strings

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

#### Code:

```
b = [' '.join(x.split('_')[:-1]) for x in a]
```

#### How?

This splits the string on the `_`, discards the last field, and then rejoins using a space.

#### Test Code:

```
a = ["Its_My_Life_3:44","Say_It_Isn't_So_3:33","Thank_You_for_Loving_Me_5:09"]

print([' '.join(x.split('_')[:-1]) for x in a]
```

#### Results:

```
['Its My Life', "Say It Isn't So", 'Thank You for Loving Me']
```

Comment: but i want to append the value in the b list

Comment: I don't understand.  Assign the comprehension to b?

Answer (score 1):

A smaller answer would be

```
import re

for song in a:
    b.append(re.match('\D*', song).group().replace('_', ' ').strip())

print(b)
```

Comment: In a line: b = [re.match(r"\D+", e).group().replace("_", " ").strip() for e in a]

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.replace()` and `r.partition()` and list comprehension

```
a = [i.replace('_', ' ') for i in a]
b = [i.rpartition(' ')[0] for i in a]
```

Expanded

```
b = []
for i in a:
    i = i.rpartition(' ')
    b.append(i[0])
```

Single list comprehension:

```
b = [(i.replace('_', ' ')).rpartition(' ')[0] for i in a]
```

Comment: Whenever you catch yourself typing `list(map(lambda` a plain list comprehension is likely faster and more readable.

Comment: @PaulPanzer your right and i just got off after I posted this cus I was tired, I completely overlooked that ty